# How to assign roles to the users in Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, rbac

I am creating a `login` module for a web portal. For this I have created a `create user` api which creates the user in Azure Active Directory. Below is how I am doing this (in Python) using the [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http):

```
user_data = {
            "accountEnabled": True,
            "displayName": "john",
            "mailNickname": "john",
            "userPrincipalName": "john@demo.onmicrosoft.com",
            "passwordProfile": {
                "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": False,
                "password": <password>
            }
        }

jdata = json.dumps(user_data)
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('graph.microsoft.com')
conn.request("POST", "/v1.0/users", jdata, headers)
response = conn.getresponse()
```

This creates the user in active directory and I am also able to login fine. To login, I am using Python's `adal` library:

```
context = adal.AuthenticationContext(config_data['AUTHORITY_HOST_URL'] + '/' + config_data['TENANT'], validate_authority = config_data["TENANT"] != 'adfs')

email = email_name + "@" + config_data['TenantName']
token = context.acquire_token_with_username_password(config_data['RESOURCE'], email, raw_data['password'], config_data['RIPE_CONNECT_CLIENT_ID'])
```

I also need to assign roles to the user I am creating. For ex, I have education portal where when account is created, user also selects if he/she is `student`, `teacher`, `parent`. Based on this, I need to assign these roles to the user so that whenever user logs in, portal knows that this user is `student` so it will show all the relevant information and will not show other data which is not relevant to student. When a teacher will log in, it will show all the data.

How can I apply `role based control system` to users in azure active directory. I have gone through some of the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview) which Microsoft has provided on it but it looks like `RBAC` is only for the user to restrict their usage of any virtual machine/web service on Azure itself.

How can I use `RBAC` in my scenario. Is there any API available which I can use to further assign roles to users. What are the other alternatives for this.

Can anyone please give me some good suggestions? Please help. Thanks

EDIT:

`config_data['RESOURCE']: https://graph.microsoft.com`

Below is the response I get in token when authenticating users using adal library:

```
{
    'tokenType': 'Bearer',
    'expiresIn': 3599,
    'expiresOn': '2020-10-26 13:19:56.881597',
    'resource': 'https://graph.microsoft.com',
    'accessToken': 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6IjU0aG03Z1psNmdqZVNmT1lCcF9jeVliTWtobklKVmdlV1Q2dHF2SnR3cTgiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6ImtnMkxZczJUMENUaklmajRydDZKSXluZW4zOCIsImtpZCI6ImtnMkxZczJUMENUaklmajRydDZKSXluZW4zOCJ9.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.qk3t_nZ0q_koA4D1QZNeBm7DLbuYxiCMNn8TC85dyQz1eY1uIZ1jhj7248z0m4CvELtp27KR8-jssiCzkW1RdUgxShscV6jRbmMPcpbR5YZ5iNZOyQxQHDSAafM0s_mJjQAA8JTwxc4yAhcKOU2R5PcVX6zbeCi28weQDs9q6vke7fCN7UPX6MKQNELBopJnQaXrvc5J9UAhvA1-_FfONnjb3zxRqb55hQuAiKpn2pRzyfD_fHViuPD2UauTZ0-1rwLRPtuMWdPl2aZNGrftfgTCeN6kxUlvunta06cdtyN6XnILCCv7mlYecPPwZi4vd5SC0hIYNIaEgciBa1pwYg',
    'refreshToken': '0.ASwAH0GQvLV2s0qvyhPREnfkS4JkG8CNKDNFjJinxegGfMgsAHE.AgABAAAAAAB2UyzwtQEKR7-rWbgdcBZIAQDs_wIA9P-wwH63zoGppq4f4Mz_zC7KfHZm8AYjxC3scz2h4HGhhHlmMNHFwj3IxE-EjTu0fgnzW-0YsRe4ELoB-3kD87Ok7NuF91NlLw2jnsVmfBu3WAbpqPDe_dGbJN6jKORHaXnSZFa32CvXht2wfj-VByzqXCBOIA3N6h61zptbSXvw4kRcobMAnftSgrzmIMwvVZIduEfnzkuSphwla_V0UxQhnAioVQUlJP90-5WRoVjLNqrmLQnaTUrY4ppeKL_u12HJZje1T2TmTHqTIfrGOZz_tvEDGsU06D2AbjTrVCfJget6D4UgKtUuo9L_dGS9PFO6OSMHSzAu32tXrB0pgxz9okm-so1ptpcSh1jtbrZATmYG4olBcEmKD_-meVrgQ7r_XH8GseBPXSSw_Bqvr55GDUbm0qGjDc3qUjHnBAeVZOPJVTKaTOK93UoUtv15DXB23UN-8xQjQ6ynjIUfC_mIJVr4m1K_sDjVAqvsvOX_gM0Zc0OwsUvB3-W_fIbr0CO1Rd38s2XfDOwkuqi8GCab6Jao5DC9rMDxekJmrc1efQvexdnijjGoTm__IGFZF2IUR_ARdJxt6UlPVrIpvAJROO5T7YIEpeR-fo6euq6txYDjiw4ImZCZ5E717lbRQsqiqLshV2TZNmf0rqRPesraBqBi8LfvEei7AdYMor5uMZpcnYPx2xKMnEnCrZBj1PkMc-quDhIoWyRNontHmTa2YbrFWGZBf61g2Y6J_P_5qySljS3JZted2A_jVd45ue2aBzcQVjxuXnKn0EEeoeq_dmxEylWxwoZYL_2hBnlNzgGD5gVXf24uL_RJvuIHat68UOSCt6hf4IwVVLGvNobhqPJO5v5YNvHdmP5P1n0KkEQJLzoyZuY',
    'oid': '1bc79085-2a1f-4fad-8da8-647f4b4b2927',
    'tenantId': 'bc90411f-76b5-4ab3-afca-13d11277e44b',
    'userId': 'testuser@demo.info',
    'isUserIdDisplayable': True,
    'isMRRT': True,
    '_clientId': 'c01b6482-288d-4533-8c98-a7c5e8067cc8',
    '_authority': 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/bc90411f-76b5-4ab3-afca-13d11277e44b'
}
```

Response when using client id as resource:

```
{
    'tokenType': 'Bearer',
    'expiresIn': 3599,
    'expiresOn': '2020-10-26 13:30:30.990330',
    'resource': 'c01b6482-288d-4533-8c98-a7c5e8067cc8',
    'accessToken': 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6ImtnMkxZczJUMENUaklmajRydDZKSXluZW4zOCIsImtpZCI6ImtnMkxZczJUMENUaklmajRydDZKSXluZW4zOCJ9.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.BkjC5-glOieUjsx3QoRs0LuWUbKlX__G9EIDHL3Uxmc1NnTFsAPgi1NdtZuimiP9r6Th976XaHzub_Z6cq_yzRVzQNEon41GGI_mrc3ejjCJnRjgxSTOhQlqiW99E58x6PATPzB2rjwpNj_BOkkAR8qWul-nUxYf071h0RLNqftUigLL85LpkLFSWgBmqp1o7m84Y5lmxPNBsMYoNw7z94lDlR79j-SjwbxhvFO-zaR2qXMw4U2yWHmjxhYx-VJ1goC_esgasutI5PUCndYewzH9pnG9uNTwDFaLpJS_FudQrPSKvr2mVFGqwpuEIfmbybj-Vd2ETPCIu8kZ-b__3g',
    'refreshToken': '0.ASwAH0GQvLV2s0qvyhPREnfkS4JkG8CNKDNFjJinxegGfMgsAHE.AgABAAAAAAB2UyzwtQEKR7-rWbgdcBZIAQDs_wIA9P8SUM1Gw4jhn-3gCk4lIUZOSxhqfoeqN6nY7DXdcjtUqsWRbzeB09CdUPwJqkwr42WqsFgQhxRc3NMxt_ZSwut2ZvrapmKCTjXzp3mXzzk3PQulqUQCa0eIgtNhrmjQoQ57L-TkprJnzIrTh2mYQMWDsSJB82jva-5EPi0dmuqvwfmBuWAjJqh1RinAmBZOtl4B5GUqTDvblJMINqV6nNJRESGU51alKLyailCumYDzWlN-ljEdY3O6Y53EwvQBfLbKIckCChXs__Tn0q4UDfmiJpVPdG1K452Jm2IhgCYsp8Uy-pPd2l1ZNObH9Vr5cadkSoAJP9v4I4g7BGokV9J9GiysR7mENhxh_oe3Yao7Mhosmid7Nveplv3BkZxbmilWp_1-11tUrGWEIjz6O1j0i9_0o6UW54SYA5Wj4hFXQ6yQX0x2QBTj7xGJBzsiJ4F3gxuZ_wCZUqyqwkxvqAg8SkK1QUpPQpOlMrfoE-db5jJ4sL1WcQ71ZSD3cfJgLRtajCPIJsutQ-It8FE6rG9Qj8k_srKB6oSKQL62J_X7bUVGLdZRjDVNhWaowam_oz4oNm7z1YELAepOJvpV__PEETAFxpl_zl2WnizKAYsSDMg8U1NZJ11Ihvyh3B_yYUKjPA46iqcWgp0WeUc93L-ZYgIdFy3j1Ie3N7p-hYXCxSdMs0UUnQUcUwgbXnwCfPEwcDdQH0WqwKBAILRml0rR-PAcSY6hUV5g51mQ3mHpfGvTtkIbDEMj2LmwGR872-JOB4gxGn4wv48AuxOrtu-GydcwucY_ev9bKs72XdwXC0vi2KGoVqv5ElJdAqjquf2doxaegCAwFe4APYeQ-AdkyR30CpuJedmp5YBESNTNB4yljreHErk9UXKkCYcCQnk',
    'oid': '1bc79085-2a1f-4fad-8da8-647f4b4b2927',
    'tenantId': 'bc90411f-76b5-4ab3-afca-13d11277e44b',
    'userId': 'testuser@demo.info',
    'isUserIdDisplayable': True,
    'isMRRT': True,
    '_clientId': 'c01b6482-288d-4533-8c98-a7c5e8067cc8',
    '_authority': 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/bc90411f-76b5-4ab3-afca-13d11277e44b'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is app roles and appRoleAssignments: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-post-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http.
You can define user roles in your app registration manifest, and then assign them through API calls to the endpoint linked above, or through the Azure AD management UI (Enterprise applications -> your app -> Users and groups).

Documentation for app roles: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps

Example defined role from the above docs:

```json
"appRoles": [
    {
      "allowedMemberTypes": [
        "User"
      ],
      "displayName": "Writer",
      "id": "d1c2ade8-98f8-45fd-aa4a-6d06b947c66f",
      "isEnabled": true,
      "description": "Writers Have the ability to create tasks.",
      "value": "Writer"
    }
  ],
```

Comment: Thanks. I have assigned the role to a user. But when I am authenticating that user with the adal library I am not getting any role related data in the returned json body.

Comment: The role should be in the claims that are part of the token. Note it'll only be returned in tokens intended for that app, so if you request a token for e.g. MS Graph API, it won't be there.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more. I didnt get you `role should be in the claims that are part of the token`

Comment: What is the value of `config_data['RESOURCE']`? What are you getting back in the `token` variable?

Comment: I have updated this detail in the questions. Please check.

Comment: Yeah since you are only getting a token for MS Graph API in that response, that won't contain the role. What you need is a token for your app. If you change the RESOURCE to the client id of your app, do you get something different?

Comment: I have changed the resource to client id but I don't see any difference. I have added this in question

Comment: Could you put the accessToken from the response to e.g. https://jwt.ms? It decodes the token, which you would need to do in code.

Comment: Okay I am with you now. I have decoded the code and got the role of the user. So basically from the code also, I will have to decode the token and get the role. Thanks